# No module named rospy, how do i fix this?

Tags: python, ros, rospy

No module named 'rospy' in pycharm, i have ros melodic and python 2.7.
in my code it is showing rospy module not found.
and when i was installing rospy module with the command : sudo apt -y install python-rospy
then it is showing :

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-rospy : Depends: python-roslib but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

i want to fix the rospy module issue in my code.

Comment: 1) python 2 is obsolete and out of support. Only use it if you're forced to. 2) packages are typically installed via `pip`

Comment: @roganjosh ros-melodic specifically targets 2.7. No good way around it right now other than updating your OS distro. Also ros is installed via `apt`, not pip

Comment: Wrong on both counts; I shall see myself out. Thanks for the clarifications

Answer (score 0):

Two potential issues can cause this. The first, and most unlikely is that you have installed ROS incorrectly. You need to make sure you're installing the full version of ROS via `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full`. You may also need to try and fix the broken packages via `sudo apt-get install -f`. Followed by a clean and upgrade: `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`; then you can try to reinstall.

If it's installed correctly you should make sure you've included it in Pycharm. You should go to `Project > Project Interpreter` and make sure `rospkg` is added.

Answer (score 0):

The error you encounter suggests that there are missing dependencies for the "python-rospy" package, which prevents its installation. To solve this problem, you should first make sure that you have installed the full version of ROS Melodic on your system. You can install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

Try installing the "python-rospy" package again:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rospy
```

In addition to making sure that the "python-rospy" package is installed on your system, it is also important to configure it correctly in Pycharm. To do this, you can follow these steps:

- Go to the "File" menu and then "Settings".
- Click "Project: [Your Project Name]" in the left column.
- Click on "Project Interpreter".
- Make sure that the "rospy" package is installed in the list of installed packages.
- If not, click on the "install" icon to install the "rospy" package.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, before performing the upgrade or update command
*($sudo apt-get update or $sudo apt-get upgrade)*, you should make sure your "*source.list*" file is compatible with your region, and ensure that the "*source.list*" is compatible with your version of the program.